# Op-amp level shifter to shift 0.33-3.3 V to 0-10 V

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, level-shifting, single-supply-op-amp

I have an input signal ranging from 0.326 V to 3.3 V and I need to amplify and shift it so that the output will swing between 0-10 V. How can I achieve that using an op-amp? I know I could do that with a level shifting circuit, but I can't figure out how to calculate the resistor values.

Comment: Homework type questions need an attempt at a solution.

Comment: Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa097/sloa097.pdf

Comment: I would recommend using two independent stages. One gain stage, and one offset stage. This requires two opamps, so you will need a dual opamp IC like the LM358.

Comment: Hint: In an inverting op-amp amplifier, you can connect the (+) input to any voltage you want; you can use this to shift your output up or down (assuming your (-) input is AC coupled, otherwise it's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Here is a "raw" schematic for you to play around with. But there is still a lot of work to do - to explain how it works, to derive the expression connecting the quantities...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fATTrd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Level shifter]

Comment: You really shouldn't provide a solution for homework type questions. You could have done it with, say, a gain of 2x and an offset of 1 volt, so the OP can modify it for the given specs.

Comment: @PStechPaul, I don't think that this "raw" circuit with adjusted resistance values ​​is enough to present as a homework solution.  As I said in my answer, there is more to be done by the OP.  But it gives them the opportunity to experiment. I could be wrong, but that is what I think at the moment...